# Creating a re-usable tikz graph template

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes, graphs

I am often making graphs for my courses, and I find that I'm always copying and pasting code, and I want to speed things up. I use my own `.cls` file for my code, so I maybe I could store some of these frequently used settings in there?

Here is my **current** code for a typical graph:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
  \def \xmin {-3}
  \def \xmax {3}
  \def \ymin {-2}
  \def \ymax {3}
  \draw[help lines] (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax);
  \draw [<->] (\xmin-.3,0) -- (\xmax+.3,0);
  \draw [<->] (0,\ymin-.3) -- (0,\ymax+.3);
  \node at (0,\ymax + .6) {$g(x)$};
  \node at (\xmax + .6,0) {$x$};
  \node at (-2, 1.5) {$y = g(x)$};
  \draw[domain=-1.828:1, blue, very thick, smooth] plot
    ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
  \draw[domain=1:2.732, blue, very thick, smooth] plot
      ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
  \draw[very thick, blue, fill] (1,1) circle [radius=.08];
  \draw[very thick, blue, fill=white] (1,2) circle [radius = .08];
  \foreach \x in {1} \draw (0,\x)node[right]{\x};
  \foreach \x in {1} \draw (\x,0)node[below]{\x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Things that are repetitive:

1. The line styles are always "very thick, blue"
2. I always draw help lines specified by values above.
3. Circles (filled white or blue) are common
4. I use the last two commands to add labels.

Some things don't scale well. If I set the scale to .5, for example, the arrows will not look correct, and text moves around. I wonder if I can change the position of arrows and the labels on the axes based on the scale factor?

If you have any thoughts on this, I would really appreciate it. I think I'm over my head in terms of both tikz and class files.

[image: Here's what the end result looks like, generally]

Comment: wouldn't pgfplots make things less verbose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `\tikzset` and `\newcommand` to create the common code to put in your `.cls` file.

For example I've created:

- a `myblue` style you can use instead of "very thick, blue"
- a `myhelp` command for the help lines
- a `whitepoint` and `bluepoint` `pic`s for the circles (filled white or blue, you may also create a unique `pic` with a parameter to pass the color option)
- a `mylabels` command to add the labels.

See the code to know how to use them:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% you may put a code like this in your .cls file
\tikzset{%
    myblue/.style={blue, very thick},
    pics/bluepoint/.style={code={%          
        \draw[very thick, blue, fill] (0,0) circle [radius=.08];
    }},
    pics/whitepoint/.style={code={%         
        \draw[very thick, blue, fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius = .08];
    }},
    }
\newcommand{\myhelp}{\draw[help lines] (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax);}
\newcommand{\mylabels}{%
    \foreach \x in {1} \draw (0,\x)node[right]{\x};
    \foreach \x in {1} \draw (\x,0)node[below]{\x};}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
  \def \xmin {-3}
  \def \xmax {3}
  \def \ymin {-2}
  \def \ymax {3}
  \myhelp  
  \draw [<->] (\xmin-.3,0) -- (\xmax+.3,0);
  \draw [<->] (0,\ymin-.3) -- (0,\ymax+.3);
  \node at (0,\ymax + .6) {$g(x)$};
  \node at (\xmax + .6,0) {$x$};
  \node at (-2, 1.5) {$y = g(x)$};
  \draw[domain=-1.828:1, myblue, smooth] plot
    ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
  \draw[domain=1:2.732, myblue, smooth] plot
      ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
  \pic at (1,1) {bluepoint};
  \pic at (1,2) {whitepoint};
  \mylabels
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course the output is exactly the same:

[image]

If it could be useful, this is the version with a parametric option for color of the arrow tip, with `blue` as default:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% you may put a code like this in your .cls file
\tikzset{%
    myblue/.style={blue, very thick},
    pics/mypoint/.style={code={%          
            \draw[very thick, blue, fill=#1] (0,0) circle [radius=.08];
    }},
    pics/mypoint/.default=blue
}
\newcommand{\myhelp}{\draw[help lines] (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax);}
\newcommand{\mylabels}{%
    \foreach \x in {1} \draw (0,\x)node[right]{\x};
    \foreach \x in {1} \draw (\x,0)node[below]{\x};}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
    \def \xmin {-3}
    \def \xmax {3}
    \def \ymin {-2}
    \def \ymax {3}
    \myhelp  
    \draw [<->] (\xmin-.3,0) -- (\xmax+.3,0);
    \draw [<->] (0,\ymin-.3) -- (0,\ymax+.3);
    \node at (0,\ymax + .6) {$g(x)$};
    \node at (\xmax + .6,0) {$x$};
    \node at (-2, 1.5) {$y = g(x)$};
    \draw[domain=-1.828:1, myblue, smooth] plot
    ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
    \draw[domain=1:2.732, myblue, smooth] plot
    ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
    \pic at (1,1) {mypoint};
    \pic at (1,2) {mypoint=white};
    \mylabels
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you CarL! -- I assume your name is CarL with a large L. This is very helpful, and I think I can blend your suggestions with what @Andrew said, and have a really great solution.

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, my name is Carla :):):) Don't forget to accept the answer you prefer!

Comment: Awww, I missed that CarLa, sorry! Thanks. I will come back and accept. I can't accept both, can I? Because they are both good.

Comment: @gnat79 Don't worry, I think the percentage of women here is little... Unfortunately you can't accept both, you have to choose... dura lex sed lex...

Comment: Etiam, quod verum est. But, there's no need to be predisposed to thinking only men know how to answer LaTeX questions. I think an unbiased view of CarLaTeX would lead people to consider both options. But we are all biased in little ways; we're all ignorant in some ways. And I don't know latin either!

Comment: @gnat79 Of course! For example, barbarabeeton is one of the worldwide LaTeX experts. I don't know Latin, too, only some quotation!

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! I'm proud to have your upvote!

Comment: @gnat79 I've added a version with a parametric option for the color of the points. 
Note that if you do a `pic` with more than one parameter, you have to explicitly give the number of the parameters in the `pic` declaration with `args`, with only one parameter, as in this case, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to use `\pgfkeys` to store various defaults for your graphs and then wrap everything inside a custom environment, with new settings given via key-value pairs. For example, the code

```
\pgfkeys{/mygraph/.is family, /mygraph,
  xmin/.initial = -3, % defaults for xmin, xmax, ymin,ymax
  xmax/.initial =  3,
  ymin/.initial = -3,
  ymax/.initial =  3,
  ylabel/.initial = f(x),% default function name
  scale/.initial = 0.9,  % tikzpicture scale
  xtics/.initial = {1}, % list of marked coordinates on x-axis
  ytics/.initial = {1},  % list of marked coordinates on y-axis
}
```

sets initial (or default), values for the maximum and minimum x and y values, the label for the y-axis and the scale. You can then define an environment, say `MyGraph` that takes an optional argument, which is passed to `\pgfkeys` via
`\pgfkeys{/mygraph, #1}` to change these settings. This would be used as

```
\begin{MyGraph}[ylabel=g(x)]
    \draw[domain=-1.828:1, smooth,-{Circle[blue]}] plot ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
    \draw[domain=1:2.732, smooth, {Circle[open, fill=white]}-] plot ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
\end{MyGraph}
```

This draws the graph in the question! In particular, note that `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` provides circular "arrow" heads. In general, the "contents" of the `MyGraph` environment will be the material specific to your graph.

The `MyGraph` environment would open the `tikzpicture` environment and draw the "initial code". Here is one possible definition:

```
\newenvironment{Mygraph}[1][]%
   {\pgfkeys{/mygraph, #1}% process settings
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\Gval{scale},
                        draw/.append style={very thick, blue}]
      \draw[help lines](\Gval{xmin},\Gval{ymin}) grid (\Gval{xmax},\Gval{ymax});
      \draw[thin, black] [<->] (\Gval{xmin}-0.3,0) -- (\Gval{xmax}+0.3,0);
      \draw[thin, black] [<->] (0,\Gval{ymin}-0.3) -- (0,\Gval{ymax}+0.3);
      \node at (0,\Gval{ymax} + .6) {$\Gval{ylabel}$};
      \node at (\Gval{xmax} + .6,0) {$x$};
      \node at (-2, 1.5) {$y = \Gval{ylabel}$};
    }
    {\end{tikzpicture}}
```

(The `\Gval` macro, which is a shortcut to `\pgfkeysvalueof{/mygraph/#1}`, extracts the value of the corresponding key.)

Notice the `draw/.append style={very thick, blue}` at the start of the `tikzpicture` environment: this sets thick blue lines as the default for the `\draw` command. There is a small disadvantage of doing it this way as it is now necessary to write `\draw[black]....` for the labels on the x and y axis. Another way of doing this would be to use 
 `\tikzset` to define a style:

```
\tikzset{% define styles for commonly used elements
  myline/.style={very thick, blue}
}
```

after which you would use `\draw[myline]...` when you wanted your thick blue lines. Using `\tikzset` is more explicit, and hence probably better, but if you want "almost all" of your drawing commands to give thick blue lines this will save you some typing.

Here is a full MWE using the `MyGraph` environment to draw two "different" graphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% Using pgfkeys makes it easier to use key-value settings for the graph
\pgfkeys{/mygraph/.is family, /mygraph,
  xmin/.initial = -3,    % defaults for xmin, xmax, ymin,ymax
  xmax/.initial =  3,
  ymin/.initial = -3,
  ymax/.initial =  3,
  ylabel/.initial = f(x),% default function name
  scale/.initial = 0.9,  % tikzpicture scale
  xtics/.initial = {1},  % list of marked coordinates on x-axis
  ytics/.initial = {1},   % list of marked coordinates on y-axis
}

% shortcut to access values of /mygraph
\newcommand\Gval[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/mygraph/#1}}

% graph environment with optional argument for changing defaults
\newenvironment{Mygraph}[1][]%
   {\pgfkeys{/mygraph, #1}% process settings
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\Gval{scale},
                        draw/.append style={very thick, blue}]
      \draw[help lines](\Gval{xmin},\Gval{ymin}) grid (\Gval{xmax},\Gval{ymax});
      \draw[thin, black] [<->] (\Gval{xmin}-0.3,0) -- (\Gval{xmax}+0.3,0);
      \draw[thin, black] [<->] (0,\Gval{ymin}-0.3) -- (0,\Gval{ymax}+0.3);
      \node at (0,\Gval{ymax} + .6) {$\Gval{ylabel}$};
      \node at (\Gval{xmax} + .6,0) {$x$};
      \node at (-2, 1.5) {$y = \Gval{ylabel}$};
      \xdef\xtics{\Gval{xtics}}% for reasons unknown can't use this directly
      \foreach \x in \xtics { \draw[black](\x,0)node[below]{\small$\x$}; }
      \xdef\ytics{\Gval{ytics}}
      \foreach \y in \ytics { \draw[black](0,\y)node[left]{\small$\y$}; }
    }
    {\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{Mygraph}
    \draw[domain=-1.828:1, smooth,-{Circle[blue]}] plot ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
    \draw[domain=1:2.732, smooth, -{Circle[open, fill=white]}] plot ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
  \end{Mygraph}

  \begin{Mygraph}[ylabel=g(x), xmin=-4, xmax=4, scale=0.5, xtics={1,2,3}, ytics={1,3}]
    \draw[domain=-1.828:1, smooth,-{Circle[blue]}] plot ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
    \draw[domain=1:2.732, smooth, {Circle[open,fill=white]}-] plot ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
  \end{Mygraph}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

You could of course add more settings to `\pgfkeys{/mygraph/,...}` to further customise your graphs. For example, you would probably want to do this for the labelled x and y values on the axes and the placement for the `y=g(x)` label etc. There are also many other things that you can do with `\pgfkeys` -- see the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual for more information.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This is very helpful. I am going to try out some of your ideas now.

Comment: @gnat79 I remembered that tikz provides "circular" arrow heads, which simplifies things a lot! I also added keys for the labels on the x and y axes.

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX! Fixed. In the image I left two variations of the white dot on the arrow heads on purpose, but my image shows that the placement is still a little off, so explicitly placing the "dots" as in your solution is better.

Comment: Yes, the placement is still a little off (also for the blue tip, of course, I didn't see it before) maybe there is some Ti_k_Z option to mend it but I don't know it!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Well, you can always fudge the domain, such as `domain=-1.8:1.1` for the first point, but this is not very satisfactory.

Comment: Yes, I've thought of a solution like that but I think there's a smartest one...

Answer (score 2):

The answers above by @andrew and @CarLaTeX are constructive and instructive. I have adopted parts of both their answers to come up with the following code.

In my class file, I have *added* the following, to an already substantial amount of (unrelated) code. I don't want to post the whole thing here, so the relevant portions are:

```
% This is the setup for the wcgraph environment below
\tikzset{%
    myblue/.style={blue, very thick},
    pics/closed/.style={code={%
            \draw[very thick, blue, fill] (0,0) circle [radius=.08];
    }},
    pics/open/.style={code={%
            \draw[very thick, blue, fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=.08];
    }},
    pics/mypoint/.default=blue,
    draw/.append style={very thick, blue},
    >=latex,
    >=stealth,
}

% This is the setup for the wcgraph environment below
\pgfkeys{/mygraph/.is family, /mygraph,
  xmin/.initial = -3,         % defaults for xmin, xmax, ymin,ymax
  xmax/.initial =  3,
  ymin/.initial = -3,
  ymax/.initial =  3,
  ylabel/.initial = f(x),     % default function name
  xlabel/.initial = x,        % default independent variable
  scale/.initial = 0.9,       % tikzpicture scale
  xtics/.initial = {1},       % list of marked coordinates on x-axis
  ytics/.initial = {1},       % list of marked coordinates on y-axis
  xticsloc/.initial = below,  % default location for tick labels
  yticsloc/.initial = left,
  helplines/.initial = draw,  % Default to draw the help lines
}

% A new command to grab values from pgfkeys above
\newcommand\getVal[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/mygraph/#1}}

% A command to draw helplines. To not draw them, pass the option "hide"
\newcommand{\helplines}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{draw}}{
    \draw[help lines] (\getVal{xmin},\getVal{ymin}) grid (\getVal{xmax},\getVal{ymax});
  }{}
}

% The graph environment with optional arguments for changing defaults
\newenvironment{wcgraph}[1][]%
   {\pgfkeys{/mygraph, #1}% process settings
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\getVal{scale}]
      \helplines{\getVal{helplines}}
      \draw[thin, black] [->] (\getVal{xmin}-0.3,0) -- (\getVal{xmax}+0.3,0);
      \draw[thin, black] [->] (0,\getVal{ymin}-0.3) -- (0,\getVal{ymax}+0.3);
      \node at (0,\getVal{ymax} + .6) {$\getVal{ylabel}$};
      \node at (\getVal{xmax} + .6,0) {$\getVal{xlabel}$};
      \xdef\xtics{\getVal{xtics}} % Can't use this directly for some reason
      \foreach \x in \xtics {
        \draw[black](\x,0)node[\getVal{xticsloc}]{\small$\x$};
      }
      \foreach \x in {\getVal{xmin},...,\getVal{xmax}}{
        \draw[black, thin, shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt);
      }
      \xdef\ytics{\getVal{ytics}}
      \foreach \y in \ytics {
        \draw[black](0,\y)node[left]{\small$\y$};
      }
      \foreach \y in {\getVal{ymin},...,\getVal{ymax}}{
        \draw[black, thin, shift={(0,\y)}] (1pt,0pt) -- (-1pt,0pt);
      }
    }
    {\end{tikzpicture}}
```

In my `.tex` file, I use the `worksheet.cls` class which (as I said above) includes a lot of other things than what I have posted directly above this. A MWE is:

```
\documentclass{worksheet}

\begin{document}

  \begin{wcgraph}[xmin=-2, ymin=-2]
    \draw[domain=-1.828:1, smooth] plot ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
    \draw[domain=1:2.732, smooth] plot ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
    \pic at (1,2) {open};
    \pic at (1,1) {closed};
  \end{wcgraph}

  \begin{wcgraph}[helplines=hide, xmin=-2, ymin=-2, scale=1.8]
    \draw[domain=-1.828:1, smooth] plot ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
    \draw[domain=1:2.732, smooth] plot ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
    \pic at (1,2) {open};
    \pic at (1,1) {closed};
  \end{wcgraph}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following graphs:

[image: Two graphs]

Perhaps this isn't the place to ask a follow up question, (and I'll be happy to edit this and post another question if someone suggests that) but I would like to extend things slightly. I believe this is highly relevant to the original question, thus the followup. I want to add a command to draw all "open" nodes needed by specifying coordinates. I have trouble passing a "list" of coordinates in the new command. I want to use `\foreach` on `#1`, the argument of my new command. This doesn't work as I expected, and it won't parse as coordinates. I've read the PGF guide and lots of posts on `\foreach` with no success.

I would like to use the following code to graph the above:

```
  \begin{wcgraph}[helplines=hide, xmin=-2, ymin=-2, scale=1.8]
    \draw[domain=-1.828:1, smooth] plot ({\x}, {-0.5*(\x-1)^2 + 2});
    \draw[domain=1:2.732, smooth] plot ({\x}, {-1*(\x-1)^2 + 1});
    \openpics{(1,2)};
    \closedpics{(1,1)};
  \end{wcgraph}
```

which would have a great benefit when I have more complex graphs.

My best guess at this new command (to be added to my `.cls` file):

```
% A new command to draw all open pics I need.
\newcommand{\openpics}[1]{
  \foreach \coord in {#1}{
    \pic at \coord {open};
  }
}
```

And the `\closedpics` command would be similar.

Comment: If you have a follow-up question then you should post it as a new question: no one will see it buried in an answer to your original question. This said, my answer provides one way of doing what you want: look at how I handle `xtics` and `ytics`.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to consider the `pgfplots` package for your purpose, a complete example follows.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle,
                    axis line style={<->},
                    xlabel={$x$},
                    ylabel={$y$},
                    line width=1pt,},
                    % line style
                    gnatplot/.style={color=blue,mark=none},
                    soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*},
                    holdot/.style={color=blue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
                    }

% arrows
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-3,xmax=3,
            ymin=-2,ymax=3,
            grid=both,
        ]
        \addplot[gnatplot,domain=-1.828:1]{-0.5*(x-1)^2 + 2};
        \addplot[gnatplot,domain=1:2.732]{-1*(x-1)^2 + 1};
        \addplot[soldot]coordinates{(1,1)};
        \addplot[holdot]coordinates{(1,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has the benefit of adding points as a list of coordinates, as well as some others. Good idea, I'll look into it.