# Converting a string to a number

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a specific macro in order to make graph display easier using Tikz.

For this purpose, I am trying to make an environment which uses many parameters. For instance, I would like to have xMin, xMax, yMin and yMax to define from where to where to display my graph, a parameter to describe where to put the legend (below or above the axes) and so on.

Therefore, I would like to make a call like this

```
\begin{graphe}[xMin=-5,xMax=5,yMin=5,
yMax=5,xAxisRight=below,xAxisLeft=below,yAxisTop=right,
yAxisBottom=right,xStep=1,yStep=1,gridStep=5,xScale=1,yScale=1]
\end{graphe}
```

I am using xString to get the values of my different parameters. My problem is the following : when I do

```
\StrBetween{#1}{xMin=}{,}
```

for instance, I do get the "-5" as expected but this is a string chain. Therefore, using this in any Tikz call will cause an error.

Although I made quite some research on the internet, I couldn't find any way to parse the string "-5" into the number -5.

I am sure I missed something and that there must be a very easy solution which I failed to find.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Edit :

```
\newenvironment{graphe}[1][]
{
\StrBetween{#1}{xMin=}{,}
\newcommand{\xMin}{-5}
\newcommand{\yMin}{-5}
\newcommand{\xMax}{5}
\newcommand{\yMax}{5}
\newcommand{\xAxisRight}{above}
\newcommand{\xAxisLeft}{above}
\newcommand{\yAxisTop}{right}
\newcommand{\yAxisBottom}{right}
\newcommand{\xStep}{1}
\newcommand{\yStep}{1}
\newcommand{\quadrillageStep}{5}
\newcommand{\xScale}{1}
\newcommand{\yScale}{1}
\renewcommand{\xMin}{\StrBetween{#1}{xMin=}{,}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
\draw[->,>=latex,very thick] (0,0) -- (\xMax,0);
}
{
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}
```

The last call

```
\draw[->,>=latex,very thick] (\xMin,0) -- (\xMax,0);
```

does generate an error but If I do the call with `-5` instead of `\xMin` it works. Therefore I thought that this was a conversion problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `tikzset` (because you tagged tikz) or better `pgfkeys` ? This is the exact reason why they are invented.

Comment: tex has neither strings nor numbers in either case you just get the pair of tokens `-` and `5` but `\StrBetween{#1}{xMin=}{,}` is not a list of tokens it expands to a sequence of definitions that would eventually typeset the result so it fails just as using `zz=\def\foo{1}\foo` will fail and not work `zz=1`

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to show your use-case. That way one can better assist you in providing solutions to the actual problem.

Comment: I did add the environnment description as it is now. Sorry, but I do not understand the first 2 answers, I am really not an expert in LaTex, I am trying my best but many of the subtleties remain totally misterious to me sadly.

Comment: @HerculePoivrot: So you don't put anything between `\begin{graphe}`...`\end{graphe}`. Only some stuff in the optional argument?

Comment: That's mainly the idea. The idea is that macro generates the axis system, a grid, and the legend. I will just have to add one command to plot my function and that's it. That's the idea. I had this working but using many functions with many arguments, and I never remembered which argument corresponded to what, therefore my idea to make something more convenient at use.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351457/creating-a-re-usable-tikz-graph-template/351473#351473

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I didn't know about this possibility, will have to have a look on that, although I am not sure it will solve my problem, it is definitely a feature worth knowing.

Comment: Actually, I think that it completely solves your problem! See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\pgfkeys` (or `\tikzset` if you prefer, although it is almost equivalent), to set defaults and process your settings. The following code fixes and slightly extends your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% Using pgfkeys makes it easier to use key-value settings for the graph
\pgfkeys{/graphe/.is family, /graphe,
  xmin/.initial        = -3,    % defaults for xmin, xmax, ymin,ymax
  xmax/.initial        =  3,
  ymin/.initial        = -3,
  ymax/.initial        =  3,
  ylabel/.initial      = f(x),% default function name
  scale/.initial       = 0.9,  % tikzpicture scale
  xtics/.initial       = {1},  % list of marked coordinates on x-axis
  ytics/.initial       = {1},   % list of marked coordinates on y-axis
  xAxisRight/.initial  = below,
  xAxisLeft/.initial   = below,
  yAxisTop/.initial    = right,
  yAxisBottom/.initial = right,
  xStep/.initial       = 1,
  yStep/.initial       = 1,
  gridStep/.initial    = 5,
  xscale/.initial      = 1,
  yscale/.initial      = 1
}

% shortcut to access values of /graphe
\newcommand\Gval[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/graphe/#1}}

% graph environment with optional argument for changing defaults
\newenvironment{graphe}[1][]%
   {\begin{center}
    \pgfkeys{/graphe, #1}% process settings
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\Gval{scale}, % set tikzpicture options
                        yscale=\Gval{yscale}]
    }
    {\end{tikzpicture}
     \end{center}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{graphe}
    \draw[->,>=latex,very thick] (\Gval{xmin},0) -- (\Gval{xmax},0);
  \end{graphe}

  \begin{graphe}[xmax=6]
    \typeout{xmin = \Gval{xmin}, xmax=\Gval{xmax}.}
    \draw[->,>=latex,very thick] (\Gval{xmin},0) -- (\Gval{xmax},0);
  \end{graphe}

\end{document}
```

As shown, to access any of the key-values inside the `graphe` environment you use the "helper function" `\Gval{...}`. The way that it is set up you can set default values for each of your keys (which is called the `initial` value by `\pgfkeys`). You only need to specify key values when they differ from the default values. The settings given to the `graphe` environment will only affect that instance of `graphe`.

For completeness, here is the expected but not very exciting output:

[image]

Note that, as in the original post, the `tikzpicture` environments are centered.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer this question. Your solution works great. I have just one last question because I like to learn from my mistakes : why does        \draw[->,>=latex,very thick] (\StrBetween{xMin=-5}{xMin=}{,},0) -- (5,0); generate an error when         \StrBetween{xMin=-5}{xMin=}{,} produces -5 as a result. I do not understand that.

Comment: @HerculePoivrot The official way to thank is to update and award green ticks:) I've never played with the xstring package so I don't really know but I would guess that it is an expansion issue. I haven't tested this, but probably `\xdef\Draw{\noexpand\draw[->,>=latex,very thick] (\StrBetween{xMin=-5}{xMin=}{,},0) -- (5,0);}\Draw` will work as it forces `\StrBetween` to expand before it is seen by the tikz `\draw` command.